# Move Visual Studio cursor to the end of opening HTML tag

Tags: html, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

Visual studio will automatically complete a `<div>` for you when you finish the tag's `>`.  This places the cursor in between the opening and closing tag like this:

```
<div>|</div>
```

(where the `|` is your cursor)

However, when you add a class (or other html attribute for that matter) to an html element, Visual studio will leave the cursor inside the quotes, like this:

```
<div class="foo|"></div>
```

Is there a command to automatically move the cursor to the first closing angle bracket like this:

```
<div class="foo">|</div>
```

It seems small, but I have to move my hand across the keyboard to move the cursor 2 spaces.  The Edit.GotoBrace command, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, is not doing this for me as it places the cursor here:

```
<div class="foo"></d|iv>
```

for some reason.

Comment: I typically find myself "typing over" the intellisense. (In your example, `F` `O` `O` `"` `>` end up being my keystrokes)

Comment: I made my example simple on purpose, but what if you have `<div id ="foo" class="bar|" data-meta="baz">...` and your cursor is where the `|` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't think it's possible in VS. You can do the following:**

- Navigate word-by-word using Ctrl+SideArrow
- Navigate the beginning or end of the line using Home or End.
- Navigate the beginning or end of the document by using Ctrl+Home or Ctrl+End
- Navigate the matching tag using Ctrl+[ or Ctrl+]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it typing directly this emmet shortcode and pressing ENTER, and it will leave you just where you want:

```
div[class=foo]
```

or

```
div.foo
```